# Use a publicly accessible .css file in a next.js project

Tags: next.js

Is it possible to host a .css file as a part of a next.js project? I need to access a .css file directly via URL, for example `https://website.com/style.css`. I presume I would have to put it in the `public` folder, and access that. If so, how? And is this the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You should put your files to the public folder to be accessible. Check the nextjs docs for more info https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving